# How to pass VmOptions to AndroidStudio via command line arguments?

Tags: android, command-line, android-studio, command-line-arguments

**quick version:**

I want to pass `studio.vmoptions` arguments to while executing `studio.sh` directly on the command line, instead of the actual `vmoptions` file.

Is it possible? How?

for example, something like `./studio.sh -Dhidpi=true`.

**use case:**

latest version of Android Studio adds support for `HiDpi` screens for Windows and Linux. Adding the `-Dhidpi=false` or `-Dhidpi=true` to the `studio.vmoptions` file will activate/deactivate the feature.

My problem is that sometimes I work on a 24" FullHD screen (`-Dhidpi=false`) and other times directly on the laptop 11" FullHD screen (`-Dhidpi=true`).

I would like to quick/easy be able to launch Android Studio with true or false without having to edit the vmoptions every.single.time. I believe that some type of cmd line argument would be the best, but I'm open to suggestions that doesn't involve creating a custom script to modify the vmoptions before launching it.

Comment: unfortunately you can't provide parameters to the executable. What you could do is to keep two different option files and change `STUDIO_PROPERTIES` env. But, off course, you have to wrap `studio` in a script

Comment: thanks @Blackbelt so I guess I'll just have two copies of the vmoptions, like `studio.hidpi` and `studip.lowdpi`, and have another script that replaces the file to the `studio64.vmoptions` and then call `studio.sh`

Comment: if you don't want to replace file, call `export STUDIO_PROPERTIES` with the path of the file you want to use

Comment: @Blackbelt I'm not sure what u meant. Would u mind write as a full answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately is not yet possible. What you could is to provide two different files. The documentation says that you can export the environment variable  `STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS` - which vmoptions file to use -. 
What you could do is to wrap studio.sh, in another script, and place it in `/usr/local/bin`. Your script could accept a parameter that indicates you which file to use. Could be for instance the path of the file itself, and export `STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS` before executing `studio.sh`.

```
#!/bin/sh
export STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS=$1
studio.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Following on @Blackbelt advice I've done two `.sh` scripts and two `vmoptions` files (all outside `android-studio` folder so that during updates all goes smoothly.

the `.sh` script is a very simple two line like this:

```
export STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS=/home/budius/studio64.vmoptions.hiDpi
/home/budius/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

now I can init any version just calling the correct script.